# Android Custom Image Button Does Not Stay Selected

Tags: android

I am currently using an ImageButton, and I want to have the effect like radio button once you select it stays selected, until someone picks another image button.  I have setup custom selector like below:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/buttonimagesel" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/buttonimagesel" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonimage" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

But this just shows the selected image for as long as the key is pressed down.  The effect i want is for it to stay selected like a radio button until the request is processed after which the whole activity including the button is redrawn.   So I want one click to put the button in a selected state and unclick does not change this.   Also I do not want the other buttons to be selectable after this happens, and I don't certainly don't want them to change images or anything like that.

Thanks

Comment: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/lightredsel" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/lightredsel" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/lightred" /> <!-- default -->

Answer (score 5):

If you need to use an `ImageButton`, you can add an `android:state_selected="true"` item and use `setSelected()` in your `onClick()` logic. You would have to take care of deselecting all the other buttons when selecting a new one. This question might be useful: [Android ImageButton with a selected state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604599/android-imagebutton-with-a-selected-state)

However you could also just use `RadioButton`s and customize their look (with `android:background` and `android:button` - these and all `CompoundButton`s have a *checked* state that work in a toggling way).

Comment: I added <item android:state_checked="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/lightredsel" /> <!-- checked --> but it still only highlights for about a second and then it reverts to normal image

Comment: Perhaps this option is state_checked is mostly for radio buttons?

Comment: @Androider I edited my answer, sorry, my first one was quite ugly.