# How to show that ImageButton is pressed?

Tags: java, android

How to show that ImageButton is pressed if i add image to it like this:

```
        Drawable testPic = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test_pic);

        button.setImageDrawable( testPic );
```

And make transparent background so that there would be just image:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

So when i press image button i don't see that it is pressed. I want that image would be highlighted or something when it is pressed.

Also every my button is created dynamically by code and i don't know what image would be and how many button there are.

So any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this should solve your problem: [ImageButton selected sate][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604599/android-imagebutton-with-a-selected-state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use a [selector](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/) for choosing all the different appearances of a UI element, including an `ImageButton`.

first comes the `state_Pressed=true` which means what does it look like when pressed. after that comes the regular which is the normal state of the button.

Comment: Is selector link relevant with answer?

Comment: @PareshMayani, thanks for the message, changed the link to a more relevant one...

Comment: +1 Now its true link with Perfect Example. @Streetboy check this and you may like it and accept this as correct answer.

Comment: Again i don't have images and i don't know what they would look like. I just want to some how highlight any image

Comment: well, than you have to create different images for every state. that's how it works. (you can make a different background color for each state using the same image)

Comment: What if i want transparent background color as i want to see just image without ImageButton background. And then want top highlight image itself. It is imposable ?
Just though, maybe i can on press add transparent black image on top of image i pressed ? But there should be a better way

Comment: everything is doable. all you need to do is use what you have and manipulate it as wanted. that is different question though...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) for that...

Answer (score 0):

You have to change Image at run time. You can achieve these with the help of xml file.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/category_listing_bg_img" /> 
<item android:state_pressed="true"   android:drawable="@drawable/category_listing_bg_img_pressed" /> 
</selector>
```

Copy this xml to your drawable folder

Comment: I can't do this because i don't know what my images would look like