# Change state of a button from code

Tags: android, android-layout

How to change the states of buttons from the code. I cannot use xml files since I am getting the images from the server.

Using :

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
```

I have got the drawable but how do I assign different states and then attach corresponding images for the button?

Comment: You mean by `state`: focused, pressed, ...?

Comment: What do you mean by "states"? selected? focused? visible?

Comment: yes exactly focused,pressed etc.

Comment: Take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604599/android-imagebutton-with-a-selected-state

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace selector images programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697528/replace-selector-images-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xml, we use `<selector>` element to do so. In code, we use [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) :

```
StateListDrawable content = new StateListDrawable();
Drawable pressedDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
//Your other drawables (focused, .....)

content.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, pressedDrawable);
//Add the other drawables the same way

Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.setBackground(content);
```

Comment: but setImageDrawable is not defined for button, is it?

Comment: I guess it should be button.setBackground(content);

Comment: You are right. I was using `ImageButton` in my code and I changed it to match yours but I forgot to change this. Edited.