# ImageButton with different states images size

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

How can I prevent an `ImageButton` from having a fixed size?
The drawables used in the selector have different size, and I want the `ImageButton` to resize itself to match the image size.

I've tried `adjustViewBounds` without success.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/picture_imagebutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/tab_background_selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how do u define your `ImageButton`?? Show the XML code.

Comment: There is nothing special, just an ImageButton with a drawable selector as source.

Comment: Besides using `ImageButton` try out with the `ImageView`. As far as its a question of setting image you can use the `ImageView` .

Comment: I want to be able to change the image depending on the state (pressed, selected etc...), that's why I'm using an `ImageButton`.

Comment: Can you post the java part where you are changing the image?

Comment: As you can see in the XML file, the `ImageButton` source is a selector, there is no java code implied in changing the image.

Comment: Take `adjustViewBounds` off. This is shrinking your `ImageButton`'s bounds to only be as big as the current image.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but it's not working.

Comment: a selector has the size of the largest image, i think

Comment: try to use resource as an xml 
please check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604599/android-imagebutton-with-a-selected-state

Comment: Check whether the workaround provided here is okay for you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15089048

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `ImageButton`, use `ImageView` because `ImageButton` cannot be resized itself based  on `ImageSize`. `ImageView` is the best alternative way that i can suggest for your problem. Acheive that by the following way:

**layout.xml:**

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image_selection"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**image_selection.xml:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
   <item android:state_focused="true" 
       android:state_pressed="true" 
       android:drawable="@drawable/default_image"/> //default_image.png is displayed when the Activity loads.   
   <item android:state_focused="false" 
       android:state_pressed="true" 
       android:drawable="@drawable/default_image_hover" />  //default_image_hover.png is an image displaed during Onclick of ImageView  
   <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/default_image_hover" />   
   <item android:state_focused="false" 
       android:drawable="@drawable/default_image"/>
 </selector>
```

**SampleActivity.java:**

```
  ImageView myImage= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    myImage.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you may have already know there is not an easy way to set drawables in a selector,
and I don't think there is an XML based solution to your problem.
Try this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/default_image"
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you need to add this code to onCreate or onResume

```
    final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                button.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("pressed_image", "drawable", getPackageName())));
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                button.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("default_image", "drawable", getPackageName())));

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You're basically doing programmatically what is done by the selector, which is not elegant. I would really like an XML based solution.

Comment: @gdelente I know it is not elegant, but this is not the same with selector. Selector doesn't resize your ImageButton. Also if you look for an XML solution only, you have to state it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an ImageButton, just use an Image an supply it with an onClick method

Comment: This obviously will do the trick but I'm looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you'll be best of using an `ImageView` as it will adjust its height. Set the property `setClickable` to use it like a button. Also swap your `RelativeLayout` for a `LinearLayout`, this will wrap its height to your `ImageButton`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="8dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture_imagebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:setClickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/tab_background_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Alternatively you can make the `LinearLayout` clickable and add a background resource (transparent when not clicked, colored when clicked) to act as a selector.

Comment: Does that works for you? The `ImageView`is not adjusting its height neither.

Comment: try using android:scaleType and set it to fitXY

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
android:background="@drawable/tab_background_selector"
```

insted of

```
android:src="@drawable/tab_background_selector"
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use styles and set different styles based on the state of the ImageBUtton. Because styles support background, size and many other properties that helps you to get full control of styling depending on problem at hand.