# Can we use state_selected and state_pressed feature in Android xmlLayout for an ImageButton?

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton, android-drawable, android-selector

This is in reference to the question asked in the following link

[Android ImageButton with a selected state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604599/android-imagebutton-with-a-selected-state?answertab=active#tab-top)

How will we use this as a selector? if we have 4 background images eg:

select_all_up.png, select_all_down.png
deselect_all_up.png, deselect_all_down.png

I Have already checked it with **state_selected** attribute but it doesn't seem to work.
Another option was to use checkbox instead of an image button, but i was still researching if we have an alternative.???

I am just a beginner in Android, just discovering how things work. Wished to have help in this topic. Thanks in Advance.

This is the selector file i wrote for it:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/select_all_down" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/select_all_up" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/deselect_all_down" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/deselect_all_up" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
```

and have used this drawable as a background for an image button:

.
.
.
.

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/selectAllImageButton"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonanim_select_all_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"/>
```

.
.
.
.

I wish to handle this issuein XML file itself rather than coming to code for Handling it.

Comment: ye we can use this .i have done this what problem u r facing in this

Comment: Actually this code doesn't work, if we wish to handle it with xml alone. In case of image button.I tested it in HTC desire...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a way around with it, making use of ToggleButton concept. But still wonder why the ImageView could not get these properties.

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/selectAllImageButton"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonanim_select_all_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:textOn="@string/empty_text"
        android:textOff="@string/empty_text"/>
```

Still.. It works well, to my satisfaction.