# Remain Highlighted in Selector.xml

Tags: android, xml

I have the following selector.xml implementation, however, it only highlights when user clicks, however I want to be highlighted until other button clicks. How could I achieve it?

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
      android:state_enabled="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/redo_off" />
  <item
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/redo_on" />
  <item
      android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/redo_on" />
  <item
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/redo_off" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining an item for

```
 android:state_selected="true"
```

as first item of your selector.

Edit :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
      android:state_selected="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/redo_on" />
  <item
      android:state_enabled="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/redo_off" />
  <item
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/redo_on" />
  <item
      android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/redo_on" />
  <item
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/redo_off" />
</selector>
```

I haven't tried it myself. If it doesn't work take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604599/android-imagebutton-with-a-selected-state) similar post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, could you please incorporate your answer with my code to make it more clear?