# Android selector only taking default value

Tags: android, android-button, android-imagebutton

I am trying to implement toggle functionality on a star button in Android. This is my imagebutton in res/my:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/star_icon"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/star"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onToggleStar"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:padding="20dp"/>
```

This is drawable/star.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item  android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"/>

</selector>
```

This is my onclick handler:

```
public void onToggleStar(View view)
    {
        view.setSelected(!view.isSelected());
    }
```

the problem I am facing is button src is always taking default value i.e. btn_star_big_off

This question has been asked before here [Android ImageButton with a selected state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604599/android-imagebutton-with-a-selected-state) and some other places as well but I am not able to figure out any problem.

### Edit

I have tried this as well

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/star_icon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/star"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onToggleStar"

        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:padding="20dp"/>
```

with other two functions same. I am using genymotion emulator.

Comment: can you try removing android:src="@drawable/star" line and change android:background="#00ffffff" to android:background="@drawable/star" , I am sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageButton` is subclass of `ImageView`,not `Button`,it's not clickable by default and it doesn't support selector drawable,so your selector won't work on `ImageButton`.

So to achieve your goal,you can set imagebutton's src programmally or change `ImageButton` to `Button`,and set `@drawable/star` as its background attr.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/2604599/android-imagebutton-with-a-selected-state , here also they used image button and selector was working fine !

Comment: but I have added android:clickable="true" ,@dex I tried that as well, but could not get it working, I am sorry if it sound childish. Please help

Comment: @FireSun I tried that as well but this is also not working, any other guess thanks, please see my edit.

Comment: @dex in your link of similar question,they make it by check the imagebutton's state and according to the state set image programmally,not by selector.

Comment: @FireSun 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item  android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star"/>

</selector>
I tried this but still this is loading empty star, this means there is a problem loading image, any idea why this is happening? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
@android:drawable/btn_star
```

is itself a built-in button selector with many items,

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false" 
          android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_on_disable" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false" 
          android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_off_disable" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_on_pressed" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_off_pressed" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_on_selected" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_off_selected" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_on_disable_focused" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_on_disable" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_off_disable_focused" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_off_disable" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_on" />
</selector>
```

So to get your code working, change

```
android:src="@drawable/star"
```

to

```
android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3892213 first try to add one more item with selected="false" after selected="true"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item  android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star"/> 
    <item  android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"/> 
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"/>
</selector>
```

then on java code first set the selection of the star to false

```
<starObject>.setSelected(false);
```

then try to put log inside click listener and check the state of star

```
public void onToggleStar(View view)
{
    Log.d("STAR", view.isSelected()+"");
    view.setSelected(!view.isSelected());
}
```